# Match two fields for highest count in a group

Tags: group-by, count

I need to determine if two fields match (SupportGroupName & PMgr) for the highest AgentCount within each SupportGroupName grouping.

This is the result of the output from my code so far but I don't know how to write the code for what I'm trying to achieve:

```
+------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| SupportGroupName | SupportGroupManager | AgentCount |     PMgr      |
+------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| AE DS            | Sarah Smith         |         16 | Honey Roth    |
| AE DS            | Sarah Smith         |          5 | Sarah Smith   |
| AE DS            | Sarah Smith         |          1 | Starr Gilley  |
| AEOpenstack      | Ron Jerrold         |          1 | Chris Lattel  |
| Agent 360        | Keith Barrone       |          1 | Brian Terrell |
| Agent 360        | Keith Barrone       |          1 | Kari Sampson  |
| Agent 360        | Keith Barrone       |          3 | Keith Barrone |
| Agent 360        | Keith Barrone       |          2 | Mike Randall  |
+------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
```

I can write a CASE statement comparing these two fields but not a comparison  just for the highest agent count in each group.

```
SELECT SG.SupportGroupName
     , SG.SupportGroupManager
     , Count(SGM.SupportGroupAgent) AS AgentCount
     , P.ManagerName AS PMgr
FROM ARSystem_Metrics.dbo.BI_CTM_SupportGroup SG
LEFT OUTER JOIN ARSystem_Metrics.dbo.BI_CTM_SupportGroupsAndMembers SGM 
  on SG.SupportGroupId = SGM.SupportGroupId
LEFT JOIN ARSystem_Metrics.dbo.BI_CTM_People P 
  ON SGM.SupportGroupAgentCorpId = P.CorporateId
WHERE SG.status = 'Enabled' 
  and SGM.SupportGroupAssociationId = 'Member' 
  AND P.status = 'Enabled'
GROUP BY SG.SupportGroupName, SG.SupportGroupManager, P.ManagerName
```

Expected results from comments:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+---------+
|  SupportGroupName | SupportGroupManager | AgentCount |     PMgr      | Match?  |
+-------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+---------+
| AE DS             | Sarah Smith         |         16 | Honey Roth    | No      |
| AEOpenstack       | Ron Jerrold         |          1 | Chris Lattel  | No      |
| Agent 360         | Keith Barrone       |         3  | Keith Barrone | Yes     |
+-------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: My columns of data didn't align properly in my output example - not sure why

Comment: Add expected results to your question to help us understand what you're after .  Also add a tag for the database version you're using and version.

Comment: Here is the expected result:
SupportGroupName SupportGroupManager AgentCount PMgr Match?
AE DS Sarah Smith 16 Honey Roth No
AEOpenstack Ron Jerrold 1 Chris Lattel No
Agent 360 Keith Barrone 3 Keith Barrone Yes